# meaning of variable equal dot

Tags: symbols, built-in-symbols, clear

I came across a program which I have written in a simplified form.

```
For[i=1,i<100, i=i+1;
func = a x^i;
func=.
];
```

What is purpose of "func=."?

Comment: A tip: whenever you encounter an unfamiliar symbol like `=.` in *Mathematica*, highlight it and press F1.

Comment: `=.` removes any rules defined for the left-hand-side.

Comment: [`Unset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unset.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=.` removes any rules defined for the left-hand side.